# Finding the vector field of the given potential function

Tags: vector-fields

Given the potential function

> $$f(V) = \cos (|X|^2), \quad X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$$

find the vector field $V(X).$

I'm not really use to do this kind of question, usually they ask the other way around: finding the potential function. Also, usually it is defined in terms of $(x, y)$ or $(x,y,z)$ and I can differentiate for each of these variables, but this time it's $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$, how to differentiate it?

I'm just doing this:

$${df\over dX_i} = -2 X_i \sin (X_i^2)$$

for  $i = 1,\dots,n$.

So what to do next? I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To find the vector field corresponding to a potential function, you just take the gradient. You need to be careful about the sum over $i$ when you use the chain rule, though.

Comment: What is $f(.)$? If $\mathbf{V(X)=X}$, then $f(\mathbf{X})=\cos⁡|\mathbf{X}|^2$.

Comment: @NgChungTak I'm so sorry, I still don't get it. Does it mean $v(x) = -2X_i sin(|X_i|^2)$ ?

Comment: @Ian what I know that the gradient is the derivative of the function in respect to each variable, I thought the $df\over dX_i$ is already the gradient?

Comment: The vector of partial derivatives is the gradient yes. But you took the derivatives incorrectly.

Comment: @hello, let me put in another way, you just like to find $v(x)$ in $f(v(x))=\cos x^{2}$, if we take $n=1$.

Comment: okay, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

$$
 F(x) = \cos \left( \theta(x) \right) = \cos \left( \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{2}} \right)
$$

$$
\nabla F = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  \partial_{x_{1}} \cos \left( \theta(x) \right) \\
  \partial_{x_{2}} \cos \left( \theta(x) \right) \\
  \vdots \\
  \partial_{x_{n}} \cos \left( \theta(x) \right) \\
\end{array} \right]
%
=
%
\frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  -x_{1} \sin \left( \theta(x) \right) \\
  -x_{2} \sin \left( \theta(x) \right) \\
  \vdots \\
  -x_{n} \sin \left( \theta(x) \right) \\
\end{array} \right]
$$